# Firebase UI for Flutter for Auth

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebaseui

Given Firebase and Flutter are both Google products I assumed the integration would be quite tight.

Whilst the Firebase API's are available in Flutter, I was surprised to see that Firebase UI isn't. It would be immensely useful to have this feature, especially given the features it supports.

There are two community plugins, both of work do not compile to iOS due to Twitter x64 compatibility issues.

Whilst a Firebase Flutter UI integration is in the works, would it be worth creating the integration with platform channels?

I think it's a huge shame we don't support this feature and it can really hinder the progress of development for apps that rely on the Firebase login features.

Comment: There are quite a few Firebase UI plugins out now that you can try: https://pub.dev/packages?q=firebase+ui Otherwise, how about https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth (everything you need, just do the UI yourself).